# Scrolling in calabash-android

Tags: android, ui-automation, calabash-android

I am trying to scroll down in calabash-android but couldn't.
Here is the code that I using for the scrolling part

In feature file:

```
Then I scrolldown until I see "Engine Light On"
```

In calabash_steps.rb:

`Then /^I scroll until I see the "([^\"]*)" text$/ do |text|
  q = query("TextView text:'#{text}'")
  while q.empty?
    scroll_down
    q = query("TextView text:'#{text}'")
  end 
end`

the error that I am getting:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the following code in the calasbash_steps.rb file.

```
Then(/^I scroll view "([^"]*)" "([^"]*)"$/) do |view,direction|
   scroll("#{view}",:"#{direction}")
end
```

In the .feature file, we can pass the view and directions in the manner you want to scroll.Here is a sample:

```
Then I scroll view "ExpandableListView" "down"
Then I scroll view "ExpandableListView" "up"
```